# RelativeLayout params for main screen widget

Tags: android, layout, widget, mainscreen

What's up guys!
Here is an example of my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/conf_RLayoutMultiSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/transparent100" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_scar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scar1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_dial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dial1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is - is it possible to change the conf_RLayoutMultiSize size through the code?
I have the cofigurantion layout where I did it easy, but can't realise how to do it on manescreen vidget.
I've tried this

```
  widgetView.setInt(R.id.conf_RLayoutMultiSize,"setLayoutParams",150+widgetBodySize);
```

but it wasn't succesful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
RelativeLayout rlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.conf_RLayoutMultiSize);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(value_width, value_height); // Set whatever parameters you want here
rlay.setLayoutParams(params); // Assign parameters to relative layout
```

Comment: yes, i know it. i want to change Layout size on manescreen widget.